# Outlook 2010 - can't see rule list in "Rules and Alert" window & rules don't work at all

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

Excuse me if my images annoy you, my English is bad, so I prefer using image to show my problem.
I've create 2 rules with name "PQA" (as evidence in my images below), but I can't see it in "Rules and Alerts" window. **And my rules don't work at all**!
Have anyone seen this issue before? Please give me a hint to fix it! Many thanks!
[image]
[image]

---

More informations:
Currently, I set up all mail to save into my local_mail_box and I can't see rule list. If I change setting to save all mails in network mail box, all things will be OK, but my company just give me 100MB network mail box, so this is not a solution.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create server rule by right clicking and defining conditions.
But it must be client only rule and the list that shows rules shows client-only rules (outlook asks this once at the first time you open rules and alerts).

Make rules from management window instead of right clicking and be sure it is client-only